# Kernel panics when MacBook goes to sleep (AppleEmbeddedOSSupportHost)

Tags: macbook-pro, mojave, sleep-wake, kernel-panic

### Issue

I have a MacBook Pro with macOS 10.14.6 installed.

Starting last week, whenever the OS would be supposed to go to sleep, it goes through a kernel panic instead, and reboots automatically. During the night, this can go on forever and when I open the lid in the morning, the device is very hot and spinning, probably because of this `sleep -> panic -> reboot` cycle.

I have some control over the frequency of kernel panics because I can control sleep from the energy preferences, but this is not a good solution of course.

### More info

- When the OS reboots after panic, I see the "Your computer restarted because of a problem." message - something like [this](https://www.tonymacx86.com/attachments/img_20151127_131800-jpg.164496/)
- Resetting SMC/NVRAM did not help
- The issue **does** happen when logging as guest user or even in the login screen
- The issue **does not** happen in safe mode
- Panic logs show that only `com.apple` kexts (plus one from intel) were loaded at crash time

### Questions

Do you have any hints about what is happening and how could I solve it? Suggestions about how to investigate deeper?

### Panic logs

Panic logs from the console. There are many of them and they are all 99% identical. For example, last loaded kext can be either `com.apple.driver.AppleHIDALService` or `com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs`. The frame addresses can also be slightly different.

```
Anonymous UUID:       D7F4F837-5D38-24B7-F171-373BB7AABC56

Wed Apr 15 05:00:27 2020

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff7f8d966ae5): "Failed to complete supporting devices sleep/wake\n"@/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppleEmbeddedOSSupport/AppleEmbeddedOSSupport-135.270.2/Source/Drivers/AppleEmbeddedOSSupportHost/AppleEmbeddedOSSupportHost.cpp:450
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff820aaf3be0 : 0xffffff8008bb058d 
0xffffff820aaf3c30 : 0xffffff8008cec0f5 
0xffffff820aaf3c70 : 0xffffff8008cdd82a 
0xffffff820aaf3ce0 : 0xffffff8008b5d9d0 
0xffffff820aaf3d00 : 0xffffff8008baffa7 
0xffffff820aaf3e20 : 0xffffff8008bafdf3 
0xffffff820aaf3e90 : 0xffffff7f8d966ae5 
0xffffff820aaf3ec0 : 0xffffff8008bef7a5 
0xffffff820aaf3f40 : 0xffffff8008bef345 
0xffffff820aaf3fa0 : 0xffffff8008b5d0ce 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedOSSupportHost(1.0)[FB08C8CC-A264-32C3-A602-6E0B012E9C9E]@0xffffff7f8d965000->0xffffff7f8d96afff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[7E3E0D11-12C4-3BCB-BA0F-880989A691DF]@0xffffff7f89abe000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleSMC(3.1.9)[355653AE-0A25-35CF-89CB-2C10E416275B]@0xffffff7f89ac7000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
18G3020

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 18.7.0: Thu Jan 23 06:52:12 PST 2020; root:xnu-4903.278.25~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 71EBCAB7-7239-36ED-A2B8-3DCEB0D5EFD1
Kernel slide:     0x0000000008800000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8008a00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8008900000
System model name: MacBookPro14,3 (Mac-551B86E5744E2388)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 60743822424
last loaded kext at 38599176038: com.apple.driver.AppleHIDALSService    1 (addr 0xffffff7f8c511000, size 16384)
loaded kexts:
com.intel.kext.intelhaxm    7.5.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDALSService 1
com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs   1.10
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.fileutil  20.036.15
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.25.11
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.7.0d0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAHardwareConfigDriver   282.54
com.apple.kext.AMDFramebuffer   2.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   282.54
com.apple.kext.AMDRadeonX4000   2.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy  3.50.14
com.apple.AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics  3.50.14
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelPCHPMC   2.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    6.0.14d4
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelKBLGraphics  12.1.0
com.apple.driver.AGDCBacklightControl   3.50.14
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.driver.eficheck   1
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.kext.AMD9500Controller    2.1.1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleGFXHDA    100.1.414
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.12.12
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.5.9
com.apple.driver.AppleFIVRDriver    4.1.0
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedOSSupportHost 1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelKBLGraphicsFramebuffer   12.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.50.14
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleVirtIO    2.1.3
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  407.200.4
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.AppleSystemPolicy 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver 138.4
com.apple.driver.AirPort.BrcmNIC    1400.1.1
com.apple.filesystems.apfs  945.275.8
com.apple.private.KextAudit 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   202
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.acm    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.serial 6.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.ecm    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.ncm    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBiBridge    1.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 282.54
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    528
com.apple.kext.AMDRadeonX4100HWLibs 1.0
com.apple.kext.AMDRadeonX4000HWServices 2.1.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAVBFamily 760.6
com.apple.plugin.IOgPTPPlugin   740.2
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUARTTransport  6.0.14d4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  6.0.14d4
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.AppleGPUWrangler  3.50.14
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 282.54
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 282.54
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   530.51
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.18d1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.14d1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssUARTv1   3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssUARTCommon   3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleOnboardSerial 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSkywalkFamily 1
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d8
com.apple.kext.AMDSupport   2.1.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    404.14
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   255.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.50.14
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    530.68
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.50.14
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink    4.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   5.6.9
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBAudio  315.6
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   206.5
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleActuatorDriver    2450.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   208
com.apple.driver.AppleHSBluetoothDriver 138.4
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   6.0.14d4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   6.0.14d4
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  2450.1
com.apple.driver.AppleInputDeviceSupport    2440.4
com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPIHIDDriver    55.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPISupport  55.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssSpiController    3.0.60
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.12.2
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    5.6.9
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    5.6.9
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme    3
com.apple.iokit.IONVMeFamily    2.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.7.9
com.apple.driver.AppleHPM   3.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.8.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssI2CController    3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssDmac 3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssGspi 3.0.60
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssI2C  3.0.60
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.2
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 493.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTDM    456.260.3
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  145.200.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   408.250.3
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   408.250.3
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.kext.CoreTrust    1
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.IOSlaveProcessor   1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  47
com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily    740.2
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.4
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
```

I have an Etrecheck report as well:

```
EtreCheck version: 5.5.4 (5106)
Report generated: 2020-04-15 14:53:06
Download EtreCheck from https://etrecheck.com
Runtime: 1:53
Performance: Excellent
Sandbox: Enabled
Full drive access: Disabled

Problem: Computer is restarting

Major Issues:
  Anything that appears on this list needs immediate attention. 
  Runaway process - A process is using a large percentage of your CPU.
  Low disk space - This machine is running critically low on free hard drive space.

Minor Issues:
  These issues do not need immediate attention but they may indicate future problems or opportunities for improvement. 
  Unsigned files - There are unsigned software files installed. Apple has said that unsigned software will not run by default in a future version of the operating system.
  Runaway user process - A user process is using a large percentage of your CPU.
  32-bit Apps - This machine has 32-bits apps will not work on macOS 10.15 "Catalina".
  Limited drive access - More information may be available with Full Drive Access.
  Kernel extensions present - This machine has kernel extensions that may not work in the future.

Hardware Information:
  MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2017)
  MacBook Pro Model: MacBookPro14,3
  2,8 GHz Intel Core i7 (i7-7700HQ) CPU: 4-core
  16 RAM - Not upgradeable
    BANK 0/DIMM0 - 8 GB LPDDR3 2133  
    BANK 1/DIMM0 - 8 GB LPDDR3 2133  
  Battery: Health = Normal - Cycle count = 252

Video Information:
  Intel HD Graphics 630 - VRAM: 1536 MB
    Color LCD (built-in) 3360 x 2100
  Radeon Pro 555 - VRAM: 2 GB

Drives:
  disk0 - APPLE SSD SM0256L 251.00 GB (Solid State - TRIM: Yes) 
  Internal PCI-Express 8.0 GT/s x4 NVM Express
    disk0s1 - EFI [EFI] 315 MB
    disk0s2 [APFS Container] 250.69 GB
      disk1 [APFS Virtual drive] 250.69 GB (Shared by 4 volumes)
        disk1s1 - Macintosh HD (APFS) (Shared - 231.77 GB used)
        disk1s2 - Preboot (APFS) [APFS Preboot] (Shared)
        disk1s3 - Recovery (APFS) [Recovery] (Shared)
        disk1s4 - VM (APFS) [APFS VM] (Shared - 1.07 GB used)

Mounted Volumes:
  disk1s1 - Macintosh HD
    250.69 GB (Shared - 231.77 GB used, 23.77 GB available, 17.13 GB free)
    APFS
    Mount point: /

  disk1s4 - VM [APFS VM]
    250.69 GB (Shared - 1.07 GB used, 17.13 GB free)
    APFS
    Mount point: /private/var/vm

Network:
  Interface en0: Wi-Fi
    802.11 a/b/g/n/ac
  Interface en6: Bluetooth PAN
  Interface bridge0: Thunderbolt Bridge

System Software:
  macOS Mojave 10.14.6 (18G3020) 
  Time since boot: Less than an hour

Notifications:
  Notifications not available without Full Drive Access.

Security:
  System Status
  Gatekeeper: Enabled
  System Integrity Protection: Enabled

  Antivirus software: Apple

Unsigned Files:
  Launchd: /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.java.Helper-Tool.plist
    Executable: /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Resources/Helper-Tool
    Details: Exact match found in the whitelist - probably OK

  Launchd: /Library/LaunchAgents/com.oracle.java.Java-Updater.plist
    Executable: /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Resources/Java Updater.app/Contents/MacOS/Java Updater -bgcheck
    Details: Exact match found in the whitelist - probably OK

  Launchd: ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.github.facebook.watchman.plist
    Executable: /usr/local/Cellar/watchman/4.9.0_2/libexec/bin/watchman --foreground --logfile --log-level --sockname --statefile --pidfile
    Details: Exact match found in the whitelist - probably OK

  Launchd: /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.intel.haxm.plist
    Executable: /Library/Extensions/intelhaxm.kext/Contents/Resources/haxm_start.sh
    Details: Exact match found in the whitelist - probably OK

  Launchd: /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Resources/com.oracle.java.Helper-Tool.plist
    Executable: /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Resources/Helper-Tool
    Details: Exact match found in the whitelist - probably OK

  Launchd: ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.google.keystone.agent.plist
    Executable: ~/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/GoogleSoftwareUpdate.bundle/Contents/Resources/GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent.app/Contents/MacOS/GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent -runMode ifneeded
    Details: Exact match found in the whitelist - probably OK

  Launchd: ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.google.keystone.xpcservice.plist
    Executable: ~/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/GoogleSoftwareUpdate.bundle/Contents/Resources/GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent.app/Contents/MacOS/GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent -runMode xpchost
    Details: Exact match found in the whitelist - probably OK

  Launchd: /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Resources/com.oracle.java.Java-Updater.plist
    Executable: /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Resources/Java Updater.app/Contents/MacOS/Java Updater -bgcheck
    Details: Exact match found in the whitelist - probably OK

  Plugin: /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin

  Preference Pane: /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/deploy/JavaControlPanel.prefPane

  Apps: 6

32-bit Applications:
  2 32-bit apps

Kernel Extensions:
  /Library/Application Support/CleverFiles/BackService.app
    SecureDisk.kext (1.0 - SDK 10.12)

  /Library/Application Support/TripMode
    TripModeNKE.kext (2.0.2 - SDK 10.10)

  /Library/Extensions
    intelhaxm.kext (7.5.1 - SDK 10.9)

System Launch Agents:
  [Not Loaded]  14 Apple tasks
  [Loaded]  172 Apple tasks
  [Running]  114 Apple tasks

System Launch Daemons:
  [Not Loaded]  36 Apple tasks
  [Loaded]  172 Apple tasks
  [Running]  126 Apple tasks

Launch Agents:
  [Not Loaded] com.oracle.java.Java-Updater.plist (? ac4c765c  - installed 2018-05-19)

Launch Daemons:
  [Loaded] ch.tripmode.TripMode.HelperTool.plist (Ludovic LEGER - installed 2019-01-21)
  [Loaded] com.apple.installer.osmessagetracing.plist (Apple - installed 2020-01-24)
  [Running] com.cleverfiles.cfbackd.plist (Justin Johnson - installed 2019-07-26)
  [Loaded] com.intel.haxm.plist (? 42f307e7  - installed 2019-05-27)
  [Not Loaded] com.oracle.java.Helper-Tool.plist (? e3fefdd2  - installed 2018-05-19)
  [Loaded] com.piriform.ccleaner.CCleanerAgent.plist (Piriform Ltd - installed 2020-03-31)

User Launch Agents:
  [Loaded] com.github.facebook.watchman.plist (? 0  - installed 2019-04-08)
  [Loaded] com.google.keystone.agent.plist (? 0  - installed 2020-03-12)
  [Loaded] com.google.keystone.xpcservice.plist (? 0  - installed 2020-03-12)

User Login Items:
  [Loaded] StartUpHelper (Spotify - installed 2020-04-10)
    Modern Login Item
    /Applications/Spotify.app/Contents/Library/LoginItems/StartUpHelper.app

Internet Plug-ins:
  ZoomUsPlugIn: 4.6.10 (20041.0408) (Zoom Video Communications, Inc. - installed 2020-04-08)
  JavaAppletPlugin: Java 8 Update 172 build 11 (? - installed 2018-05-19)

User Internet Plug-ins:
  User Internet Plug-ins need Full Drive Access

Audio Plug-ins:
  AppleTimeSyncAudioClock: 1.0 (Apple - installed 2019-06-04)
  BluetoothAudioPlugIn: 6.0.14 (Apple - installed 2020-02-06)
  AirPlay: 2.0 (Apple - installed 2020-02-06)
  AppleAVBAudio: 760.6 (Apple - installed 2019-08-08)
  BridgeAudioSP: 5.52 (Apple - installed 2020-02-06)
  iSightAudio: 7.7.3 (Apple - installed 2019-08-08)

User Audio Plug-ins:
  User Audio Plug-ins need Full Drive Access

User iTunes Plug-ins:
  User iTunes Plug-ins need Full Drive Access

3rd Party Preference Panes:
  Java (? - installed 2018-03-28)

Time Machine:
  Time Machine information not available without Full Drive Access.
  7 local snapshots
  Oldest local snapshot: 2020-04-14 13:26:35
  Last local snapshot: 2020-04-15 12:45:56

Performance:
  System Load: 2.61 (1 min ago) 2.62 (5 min ago) 2.24 (15 min ago)
  Nominal I/O speed: 4.23 MB/s
  File system: 27.80 seconds
  Write speed: 362 MB/s
  Read speed: 2524 MB/s

CPU Usage Snapshot:
  Type Overall
  System: 17 %
  User: 38 %
  Idle: 45 %

Top Processes Snapshot by CPU:
  Process (count) CPU (Source - Location)
  Other processes 301.83 % (?)
  Console 90.90 % (Apple)
  trustd 24.06 % (Apple)
  Activity Monitor 10.13 % (Apple)
  EtreCheck 6.63 % (App Store)

Top Processes Snapshot by Memory:
  Process (count) RAM usage (Source - Location)
  EtreCheck 912 MB (App Store)
  App Store 343 MB (Apple)
  Google Chrome 314 MB (Google, Inc.)
  Upwork 270 MB (Upwork Global Inc.)
  Activity Monitor 242 MB (Apple)

Top Processes Snapshot by Network Use:
  Process (count) Input / Output (Source - Location)
  Spotify 631 KB / 229 KB (Spotify)
  Other processes 185 KB / 200 KB (?)
  SystemUIServer 0 B / 192 B (Apple)
  mdworker_shared 0 B / 0 B (Apple)
  spindump_agent 0 B / 0 B (Apple)

Virtual Memory Information:
  Physical RAM: 16 GB

  Free RAM: 2.54 GB
  Used RAM: 8.70 GB
  Cached files: 4.76 GB

  Available RAM: 7.30 GB
  Swap Used: 0 B

Software Installs (past 30 days):
  Install Date Name (Version)
  2020-03-26 Safari (13.1)
  2020-04-04 MRTConfigData (1.58)
  2020-04-08 Zoom (4.6.20041.0408)
  2020-04-08 XProtectPlistConfigData (2118)
  2020-04-15 EtreCheck (5.5.4)

Diagnostics Information (past 7-30 days):
  Directory /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports is not accessible.
  Enable Full Drive Access to see more information.

End of report
```

Comment: Hi. did you found the solution?

Comment: No @Abhimanyu . I have changed the sleep time to a couple of hours, so I don't hit it during the day, and now I always turn the Mac off at night. Please let me know if you find a better one